# Texmaker bibliography issues

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am having issues with trying to compile a bibliography using TexMaker (I'm very new to LaTex). I have found multiple Google hits with the same error message as I've been having all day

```
The top-level auxiliary file:..... I found no \bibdata command-"
```

and I found a walkthrough using `biblatex` from Cambridge University

http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/biblatex.html

but I still can't compile the bibliography for some reason. This is my MWE:

```
%test1.tex
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{biblatex} 
\bibliography{refs} 

\begin{document} 
Hello\cite{KandR}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

The `refs.bib` is as follows.

```
%refs.bib

@BOOK
  {KandR,
   AUTHOR  = "Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.",
   TITLE   = "{The C Programming Language Second Edition}",
   PUBLISHER = "Prentice-Hall, Inc.",
   YEAR = 1988
  }
```

I perform `PDFLatex -> Bibtex -> PDFLatex -> PDFLatex`. During the first `PDFLatex` I get the following error message.

```
No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
Citation 'KandR' on page 1 undefined
Empty bibliography
>There were undefined references.
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) test1(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

and the error message associated with `BibTex`

```
Process started
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary file: test1.aux I
found no \citation commands---while reading file test1.aux I found no \bibdata command---
while reading file test1.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test1.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
Process exited normally
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems that you are using `bibtex` during compilation. `biblatex` uses `biber` by default. Use `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` instead of `\usepackage{biblatex}`

Comment: Or run biber where that guide tells you to run bibtex. biber is newer and supports features of biblatex not possible with bibtex so use biber if it is available.

Answer (score 4):

The error

```
No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
```

gives the hint that `biblatex` is using `biber`. But you are  using `bibtex` during compilation. `biblatex` uses `biber` by default (when no backend is specified). You can over come this by using

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

to force `biblatex` use `bibtex` as the backend.